# Euler-Lagrange equation; deriving it and understanding an example

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations, chain-rule, euler-lagrange-equation

I am currently reading about Calculus of Variations, and I have two questions:

The author introduces the Euler-Lagrange equation $F_{y'y'}y'' = F_y - F_{y'y}y' - F_{y'x}$. The final step in which the author derives it, he uses the chain rule to calculate

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}) = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y'\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y'\partial y}\cdot y' + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y'^2}\cdot y''$.

Perhaps this is just some elementary derivations going on, but I don't understand how one would go about doing taking the derivative of a partial derivative w.r.t a dependent variables derivative (I think I got that right). I.e. I have no clue what is going on here. Any clarily here would be appreciated.

He then gives an example of a function $F(x, y, y') = y\sqrt{1 + (y')^2}$, and says that $F_{y'x} = 0$ since the function is independent of $x$. But $y$ is a function of $x$, so this isn't exactly true. Right?

Am I wrong? And if so, what could be the root of my misunderstanding here?

Comment: The key point in calculus of variations is that when we're extremising a functional $\int F[x,y,y']\;dx$, we treat $x$, $y$, $y'$ as *independent*. One good way to internalise this intuitively: suppose your functional is $\int F[t,x,x']\;dx$, where $t$ is time. $x$ is position, $x'$ is speed. Then although $x$ and $x'$ seem related, at any instant in time they are independent. The functional $F$ doesn't care about the fact that as time evolves, $x$ and $x'$ are dependent -- it only cares that at any particular snapshot of time, there's no relation between the two.

Comment: Continuing from above, your prof means that $F=y\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$ doesn't have any *explicit* dependence on $x$, i.e. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0$. This is different from requiring $\frac{dF}{dx}=0$.

Comment: As for your first question -- perhaps it would help to write $G(x,y,y')=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$, then apply the multivariate chain rule to $G$.

Comment: Thank you @jlammy! I like your intuitive explanation. For the first part, I understand now how it works but it still is confusing since in the first case when using the chain rule, you treat $y$ as being dependent of $x$ when by itself, but inside the functional $F$ they are independent. So $\frac{dy}{dx} = y'$, but $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 0$ if $F$ has no _explicit_ variable x in its expression!